# CHECK THE LISTBOX ITEM

Tags: vb.net

when I enter TEXT in sub-serial, MUST BE CHECK FIRST IF THE TEXT IS ALREADY IN LISTBOX.ITEMS

***how do I check the listbox.item = subserial.text?***

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For Each a As String In String.Join(vbCrLf, ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String))
        If txtSS.Text = a Then
            MsgBox("It's already barcoded!")
            txtSS.Text = ""
        End If
    Next
```

I GOT IT!